# Retrofit add custom headers as token - java

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I just learn the basic of retrofit android however i have so many question regarding headers.

I have a REST API server and before my api export data it request to have API KEY which is stored on Header Authorization. now on my case before executing i want to initialized the API KEY into the header.

here's my code

```
public interface VerifyClient{

    @Headers("Authorization: eNortjI0s1LKTSxKSUyvckguLcuv0EtJ") // <======================
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/sendcode/{id}")
    VerifyResponse verify(@Path("id") String id, @Field("to") String to, @Field("type") String type, @Field("code") String code);

}
```

This work fine but the problem is what if another client api key?

another approach is this.

```
RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor()
            {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", ApiKey); <======================
                }
            };

            return new RestAdapter
                    .Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(Var.REST_URL)
                    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                    .build()
                    .create(VerifyClient.class)
                    .verify(userData[0], userData[1], userData[2], userData[3]);
        }
```

But it return `401 Unauthorized` hmmm anyone has a solution for this? or maybe i implemented it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it.

First, this is my client. Note the request header "Authorization": I have to put the keyword "Token " before the actual token.  Perhaps this could help you.

```html
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String token) {

        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));

        if (token != null) {
            builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token " + token);
                }
            });
        }

        RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();

        return adapter.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

I found that Retrofit client in the following link [Retrofit — Token Authentication on Android](http://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

If You want create API KEY for Your user I propose You at first made POJO object, which represents Yours user.

```
    static class User {
        @SerializedName("identifier")
        String identifier;

        @SerializedName("password")
        String password;

        public User(String username, String password) {
            this.identifier = username;
            this.password = password;
        }
    }
```

Next step create `Service` which handle Yours `POST` request.

```
    public interface HttpService {
        @POST("path")
        Call<Object> postWithJson(
                @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                @Header("Token") String token,
                @Body User user
        );
    }
```

And now You only must call service, for example:

```
String apiKey = 52d5bc6ecc5fasdad123124125r23fsd12312;

Call<Object> call = service.postWithJson("application/json; charset=UTF-8", apiKey, new User("login", "password"));
```

And in response get what You want, example:
`response.headers().get("tokenKey")`